# XBRL package "Error in fileFromCache(file)"

Tags: r, xbrl

I'm trying to read this `xbrl` file with R `XBRL` package...

[https://www.cnmv.es/Portal/Consultas/wuc/DescargaXBRLIPP.ashx?t={77853e69-5deb-4bd5-acd4-3fb4715e2664}](https://www.cnmv.es/Portal/Consultas/wuc/DescargaXBRLIPP.ashx?t=%7B77853e69-5deb-4bd5-acd4-3fb4715e2664%7D)

...but when I download the file and run the code

```
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(inst, verbose=TRUE)
```

I get this error:

> error in XBRL::xbrlParse(file) :
>       ./ipp-enc-ind-2005-06-30.xsd./ipp-enc-con-2005-06-30.xsd does not exists. Aborting.

I suppose that the error is a problem with the ULR of the `.xsd` file. Is it possible to download the `xsd` files in a local directory and use them to read the `.XBRL` file? How can it be done?